# Python: How to use a previously instantiated class object when multiple calls to a class is made?

Tags: python, class, oop, caching

I have an inference class that reads "group" specific csv files (required for making an inference on an image) in its init method like so:

```
Class Inference:

    def __init__(self, group: str):
          filename = group + ".csv"
          self.file = pd.read_csv(filename)

    def predict(self, img):
    """Function to predict"""
```

Also, I have a script that calls this class for inference for each image, like so:

```
def get_inference(img, group):
    model = Inference(group)
    result = model.predict(img)
```

**Problem:**

If I am passing a sequence of images for the same "group", the "Inference" class gets instantiated every time and the csv file will be read for each instantiation.

I would want that if the "group" is same for repeated calls, then do not instantiate the class again.

However, if the "group" name changes, I would want the class to get instantiated and read the new group's csv file.

*How to do this while making it thread safe?*

Online, I have found some posts about using LRU_cache and singleton class. I do not know about either of them. Which one should be used?

Thanks!

Comment: You only show 1 group being used: test_group. How do you instantiate other instances?

Comment: Other groups could be test_group_2, test_group_3 and so on..

Comment: Does this mean your function is more like: ‘def get_inference(img, group):’?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the correction! I edited the code to include the group parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your could add another parameter for a cache:

```
cache = {}

def get_inference(img, group, cache):
    if group in cache:
        model = cache[group]
    else:
        model = Inference(group)
        cache[group] = model
    return model.predict(img)

result = get_inference(img, group, cache)
```

Comment: So we are storing the class instance in a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, precisely. This means that for the same `group` again, the previous instance is fetched instead of creating it again.